# In the GDI + error general form

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I have directory, in directory image background.jpg

In the early work I load this image in background

```
ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
imgBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/background.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
border.Background = imgBrush;
```

after which the pattern during, I need to change this image.
I shake it from the server, try to write in images/background.jpg and I get an exception

"In the GDI + error general form" - this is translate for russian.

get image for server and save to computer

HttpWebRequest loHttp = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(request);
loHttp.Method = "GET";
loHttp.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
HttpWebResponse loWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loHttp.GetResponse();

```
StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(loWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
System.Drawing.Image webImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(loWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
try
{
    webImage.Save("images/background.jpg");//this exception

    ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
    imgBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/background.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    parent.GetSetBorder.Background = imgBrush;
}
catch {  }
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this code will work only once.  After you called Save(), you've got a lock on the file.  Saving again will bomb.  You must call Dispose() after calling Save() so the bitmap is disposed properly and the file lock is released.

Not using the *using* statement or calling Dispose() on a disposable class object is something you often get away with in .NET.  But rarely on bitmaps.

Comment: webImage.Despose - is not helped me =(.

Comment: Good, I hoped it wouldn't.  You marked the wrong statement for the exception.  Image.FromStream() cannot read from a NetworkStream, it needs a stream that supports Seek().  You'll need to read the data from the stream into a MemoryStream first.

Comment: Yes, our failure to communicate is obvious.  It's been that way as long as can remember helping you.  Couple of years now?

Answer (score 0):

The path you are saving to (images/background.jpg) is pointing to your local computer and this error can occur when the path does not exist.

Try writing a `webImage.Save("c:\\background.jpg");` or any other path known to exist to see if the error persists.